# OpenSSH AuthorizedPrincipalsFile Allows Any User

Tags: authentication, certificates, certificate-authority, account-security, openssh

I am bewildered as to the below config and subsequent behaviour.

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/principals
```

/etc/ssh/principals:

```
all
host.example.com
dev
```

This allows me to login as *ANY* user using my cert which has one or more matching principals.

What am I missing here?

I see now it's meant to be:

```
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/principals/%u
```

but surely my (mis)configuration should not allow any user?

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior. Basically if you specify a static, unparameterized `AuthorizedPrincipalFiles`, then the same file is used for all users. If you want user-based control, you have to use the `%u` thing.

What happens under the hood becomes clearer if you look at the `AuthorizesPrincipalsCommand`. That one runs the specified command, passing the user as an argument. Said command can be anything but should output a valid principals string to stdout, which sshd will then proceed to use as principals file.

Now think of

```
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/principals
```

conceptually of the same as

```
AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand /bin/AuthorizedPrincipalsFile
```

where `AuthorizedPrincipalsFile` is a program that discards the user parameter and just returns a static string:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /bin/AuthorizedPrincipalsFile

echo "I'm not using this: $1" >/dev/null

cat /etc/ssh/principals
```

So as long as the principal(s) mentioned in the key's certificate is also in the servers static `/etc/ssh/principals`, the key's owner can log in as every user.

See manpage: https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand

Comment: Thank you. I went with `AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand` that is a simple Bash script that compares the Key ID with the username. If they don't match then exit.